# Can´t get form to insert data

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am struggling with a form inserting into a mysql database. Upon filling out the form i get the following error message

```
bad query: INSERT INTO gjenstand(idselger,bilde,beskrivelse,idkategori,minstepris,utlopsdato) VALUES (1,23.jpeg,TVbord,,950,2018-06-23)
```

The information that is not inserting have the following code:

```
$conn=mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","root", "bruktbutikk");
    $sql1="select beskrivelse from kategori";
$datasett1 = $conn->query($sql1);


if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $sql =sprintf("INSERT INTO gjenstand(idselger,bilde,beskrivelse,idkategori,minstepris,utlopsdato) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",

                  $tilkobling->real_escape_string($_POST["lstnavn"]),
                  $tilkobling->real_escape_string($_POST["txtbilde"]),
                  $tilkobling->real_escape_string($_POST["txtbeskrivelse"]),
                  $tilkobling->real_escape_string($_POST["lstkategori"]),
                  $tilkobling->real_escape_string($_POST["txtminste_pris"]),
                  $tilkobling->real_escape_string($_POST["txtutlopsdato"])

         );

         $tilkobling->query($sql,$sql1) or die ("bad query:$sql");
```

and here is the code for the form with the missing value:

```
 <form method="post">
        <div>
        <label for="lstkategori">Kategori:</label>
        <select name="lstkategori" id="lstkategori">
         <?php while($rad=mysqli_fetch_array($datasett1)) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $rad["idkategori"]; ?>"> <?php echo $rad["beskrivelse"]; ?>
             </option>}
            <br><br><br>
         <?php } ?> <br><br>
         </select>
```

Thank you so much in advance, for taking time out of your day and help me out<33

Comment: You don't need to escape the values if you are passing them in as parameters.

Comment: You can't pass two queries to `$tilkobling->query()`.

Comment: Based on the bad query line at the top of your post it looks like at least one of the values on the form isn't being completed and since you are doing no checking at all to see if it is there the resulting SQL query is invalid (notice the 2 commas in the values section).

Comment: What is `$tilkbling`, shouldn't that be `$conn`?

Comment: I have to both $tilkobling and $conn as defined variables

Comment: @Dave yes, the query tells me that one of the table columns is not getting inserted into, that table column has the form at the bottom of my post.the data is not inserting into "idkategori"

Comment: No need to add "solved" in a title: instead, mark an answer as accepted using the green checkmark. Or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the values that contain strings.

```
$sql =sprintf("INSERT INTO gjenstand(idselger,bilde,beskrivelse,idkategori,minstepris,utlopsdato) VALUES (%s,'%s','%s','%s',%s,'%s')",
```

But it's best to use a parametrized query instead:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO gjenstand(idselger,bilde,beskrivelse,idkategori,minstepris,utlopsdato) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("isssis", $_POST["lstnavn"], $_POST["txtbilde"], $_POST["txtbeskrivelse"], $_POST["lstkategori"], $_POST["txtminste_pris"], $_POST["txtutlopsdato"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @Barmar unfortunately it still does not insert into into the 4th column "idkategori". The error code still displays the value for the 4th column as blank. But thank you very much anyways. As for the second suggetion, i have never tried parametrized queries, so i dont know how i should use it. Do i need to put the $stmt variable somewhere?

Comment: The 4th column is blank because the value of the variable is blank.

Comment: I've shown you the exact code that you need to use for parametrized queries. It replaces everything after `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: Thank you, i got it working, allthough i still get no value inserted into my idkatergori column. I suspect something may be wrong with the form itself for that particular item. Upon Changing it from a list to a txt i succeeded in entering the value, but this is obviously not very user friendly, as the user needs to know the different category id numbers.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML source to make sure that the correct value is being put into `value=""` of the options?

Comment: Yes you are correct sir! it Appears as  when inspecting the functioning <option> the id is displayed correctly, but upon inspecting the not functional <option> i only get the content, but the id the options that are 
 supposed to be connected to are not appearing in the inspect element. In other words the value="" is missing.

Comment: Thanks to you Barmar i was able to find the issue and fix the problem. It is working now!